# uwsgi is running my app as root, but shouldn't be

Tags: python, flask, permissions, uwsgi, supervisord

I have a `Flask` app run via `uwsgi` being served by `nginx`, all being controlled by `supervisord`

I have set my `user` parameter in `/etc/supervisor.conf` to `user=webdev`

and in both `../myapp/uwsgi_app.ini` and `/etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini`, I have set `uid=webdev` and `gid=www-data`

Problem is, I am having a permissions issue within my app. with the following `print` statements in one of my views, I discover that the application is being run as `root`. This is causing issues in a function call that requires creation of a directory.

All of the following print statements are located inside the `Flask` view.

```
print 'group!! {}'.format(os.getegid())
print 'user id!! {}'.format(os.getuid())
print 'user!! {}'.format(os.path.expanduser('~'))
```

results in...

```
group!! 1000
user id!! 1000
user!! /root
```

EDIT: I added the following print statements:

```
from subprocess import call
print 'here is user',
call('echo $USER', shell=True)
print 'here is home',
call('echo $HOME', shell=True)
```

This prints

```
here is user root
here is home /root
```

in a terminal on the server, I type `$ id`, I get `uid=1000(webdev) gid=1000(webdev) groups=1000(webdev)`

Here is the output from `$ getent group`

```
root:x:0:
...
webdev:x:1000:
...
www-data:x:1001:nginx
nginx:x:996:nginx
...
```

Here are some lines from `/etc/passwd`

```
webdev:x:1000:1000::/home/webdev:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, because normally you wouldn't have any permissions issues when running as `root` (the opposite actually, you'd have more permissions than necessary in this case).

I have the feeling that you might be running the process as `webdev` and not `root` after all. Can you try calling `os.getuid()` instead of `os.expanduser()`?

The `/root`directory is often used as a default when there is no home directory set for a user. You can also check your `/etc/passwd/` for `webdev`'s entry to see what the home directory is set to.

If you're not running as `root`, your permissions issue are probably related to something else (maybe `webdev` isn't the owner of the directory you're writing in?).

EDIT: If you want user `webdev` to have a proper home directory, run the following as `root`:

```
mkdir -p /home/webdev
usermod -m -d /home/webdev webdev
```

After that, `os.expanduser()` should display the correct home directory.

EDIT 2: I was wrongly assuming that `webdev` was not a normal user but just a minimally configured service username like `www` that you were using. My mistake.

In any case, as I mentioned in the comment, what matters is your `uid` value. You're not running as root because your `uid` is not 0. Nothing else matters in UNIX terms.

I think that I figured it out though. The way uWSGI works when you specify the `uid` & `gid` options is that it still runs as `root` originally but immediately calls `setuid()` to drop its privileges and switch to the `uid` and `gid` you provided. This would explain the behavior you're seeing: the environment is still configured for `root` and even though uWSGI is now running as `webdev`, `$USER` and `$HOME` must be still pointing to `root`.

You can try to test this by adding this line inside the Flask view:

```
open('/home/webdev/testfile', 'a').close()
```

This will create an empty file in webdev's home directory. Now log in afterwards as `webdev`, go to `/home/webdev` and do an `ls -l`. If the owner of `testfile` is `webdev`, you're running as `webdev`.

If you can establish that, then what you'll have to do is write all your code assuming that `$HOME` and `$USER` are wrongly set. I'm not sure how it will affect your code, but try, for instance, to avoid relative paths (it is possible assumed that the default destination is your wrong home directory).

Comment: question edited to add user id (group id and `os.expanduser()` were already in there). I am confused why it shows user id and group id as webdev, but `expanduser()` shows root. (I do not want to run as `root`, I want to run as `webdev`)

Comment: @Brian, you're **not** running as `root`. It just seems that `expanduser()` is confused about `webdev`'s home directory which might be either set to `/root` or not set at all. If you want to fix that, see my edited answer.

Comment: if I run `os.path.expanduser('~')` in a python terminal, I get my proper home directory to show up. Also, running `echo $HOME` gives me the proper directory.

Comment: @gbt If I use the commands `subprocess.call('echo $USER', shell=True)` and `subprocess.call('echo $HOME', shell=True)`, I get `root` and `/root`. Turns out I am running as root.

Comment: @BrianLeach The commands in the edits in my answer wouldn't cause any harm in any case, whether your configuration was correct or not. Now that I hope that we established that I was just trying to help you: you're still not running as root because your uid is not 0. Nothing else, not your home directory, not the environment variables, nothing matters except the process's uid. I may have another explanation which I'll add to my answer shortly.

Comment: It looks like the `uwsgi` settings only allow to set the user id and group id (`uid=webdev, gid=www-data`). I am confused at how the whole system treats user IDS and user names differently. As you pointed out, the user id doesn't match `root`, but the program is choking where it tries to determine the home directory using `os.expanduser('~'). I tried the testfile trick and sure enough, `webdev` is the owner of that file. Problem is, the error occurs in a third-party library (`bokeh`) so I can't safely start changing things in `bokeh`

Comment: First of all, try to fix the environment variables from within Python (use `os.environ`). But most likely your permissions issues have nothing to do with the `$USER` and `$HOME` variables. bokeh is widely used and deployed so it's almost certain that it's a misconfiguration on your part, most likely a permissions issue. Where are you serving your app from? Make sure that the ownership and permissions in that directory are correct and grant write access wherever appropriate.